# Access classes in implicitly loaded Jenkins global library

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a global library configured in Jenkins. It works. But when my Pipeline is stored in SCM, it tells me that it cannot find it when I tried to load it. A workaround is to load it implicitly.

But how can I access the classes in the library then? I can not do

```
@Library("mylib") import ...
```

Because that triggers the error.

Comment: what about this doc, https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/?

Comment: I can not find anything in there that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm getting used to this myself at the moment.

I initially read https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#loading-libraries-dynamically to mean that unless you're in a Jenkinsfile, you need to use the syntax:

```
library 'mylib'
```

**However**, I have since realised that actually you can use `Library` but need to include an underscore or a specific import, i.e.

```
@Library('mylib') _
```

See https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42807?attachmentViewMode=list for where I discovered that.

Does that help at all?